# Picture Format with frame.pack()

Tags: java, image, jbutton

With this code, I visualize a picture after performing a search . The user has the possibility to change that image selected by clicking a button and then opening a picture editor (this is not the main point at the moment) ,  I would put a button in the right side of the image. Now with the pack () , the window size is the same as the picture, how do I insert a button ( with its image) keeping fixed the other three sides or at least having the same distance from right and left ?

```
public static void VisImmagine(JFrame frame, String Indirizzo)
    {

        Image image = null;
        try {

            URL url = new URL(Indirizzo);
            image = ImageIO.read(url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
        }


        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        frame.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
//      frame.setSize(10, 10);
        frame.pack();
        ////UPDATE
        int larghezza = frame.getWidth();
        int altezza = frame.getHeight();
        frame.setSize(larghezza+250, altezza)
        //////
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
```

Hope I was clear enough, thanks in advance to everybody.

Comment: Could you post an image of desired output? And a code we can copy-paste (it would be faster for us to help you) C:

Comment: Hi @Frakcool , I have solved in this way: int larghezza = frame.getWidth();
  int altezza = frame.getHeight();

  frame.setSize(larghezza+250, altezza)

Comment: @Frakcool I can not edit the comment above, so considered this one instead of the first one.   I updated the code above. Maybe It was better a picture to explained what I wanted, as you asked. However, the piece of code that I added( it starts from UPDATE and ends in ////// ) it could also be removed , at the end I will use the double mouse click event instead of a button. Thank you for participating

Comment: as I said, a picture (A paint draw would be enough) from actual and desired output would be ok. Also adding your `image` image on your post. No, you can't edit comments after 5 minutes. You're saying you solved your problem, please post as answer and accept if that's the case.